# How to "spawn" and delete UIImage views programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I use the following code to add UIImageviews to the view inside a method that is calling every 10 seconds:

```
   //every 10 seconds
 numberofObjects++;
    UIImageView *Object = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random()%248+36,arc4random()%496+36,36 ,36)];
    Object.tag = [self.view.subviews count]+1;
    UIImage *imag = [UIImage imageNamed:@"power-up1.png"];
    [Object setImage:imag];
    [wallarray addObject:Object];
    [self.view insertSubview:Object atIndex:[self.view.subviews count]];
```

Then i use this code which is inside a method that is calling every 0.03 seconds to remove the subview from the view:

```
 //every 0.03 seconds
 for (UIImageView *views in wallarray) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(views.frame, yellow.frame) || CGRectIntersectsRect(views.frame, green.frame)) {
            wall = YES;
            numberofObjects--;
            for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
                if (views.tag == views.tag) {
                    [subview removeFromSuperview];
                    break;
                }
            }
            [wallarray removeObjectIdenticalTo:views];
            if (!wallarray) {
                wallarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

It works 95 % of the time but sometimes it won't get removed from the view. However, it will get removed from the wallarray array. The problem seems to get worse the more UIImageviews I add to the view. If someone could tell me a better way to deleting image views from a view or tell me what is wrong with the code i would be happy.

Comment: First of all, why you use `NSArray` to keep references to image views? It's enough to use `self.view.subviews` array.

Comment: Well first of all, you might want to review that `views.tag == views.tag` condition. Also, the variable names should start with the lowercase letter (in case of `Object`).